# Sample without replacement in golang

Tags: go, random, slice, sampling

What's the best way to sample without replacement from a slice in golang?

```
a := make([]int, 100)
for i := range a {
    a[i] = i
}

# TODO sample 5 elements from a without replacement.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the set size is relatively small overall, or you are sampling a large portion of the set, the simplest method is to shuffle the elements and pick the first `n`:

```
rand.Shuffle(len(a), func(i, j int) { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] })
fmt.Println(a[:5])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lQx44Mn9RQL

If you don't want to shuffle the entire set, but it's acceptable to alter the order of the set (or copy the entire set), you can "record" the used values more efficiently by removing them from the slice.

```
// create a copy of the slice header
c := a
samples := make([]int, n)

for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    r := int(rand.Int63n(int64(len(c))))
    samples[i] = c[r]

    // remove the sample from the copy slice
    c[r], c[len(c)-1] = c[len(c)-1], c[r]
    c = c[:len(c)-1]
}
```

In the case that the set size is quite large and you are sampling only a small portion, you can sample from the original set without modification by recording the sample index and not repeating it. Obviously as the ratio of the sample size to the set size grows, the number of collisions will grow making this less efficient.

For example:

```
// record indexes here to prevent duplicates
indexes := make(map[int]bool)

// create n random indexes
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    var r int
    for {
        r = int(rand.Int63n(int64(len(a))))
        if indexes[r] {
            continue
        }
        break
    }

    indexes[r] = true
}

samples := make([]int, 0, n)
for i := range indexes {
    samples = append(samples, a[i])
}
```

Comment: This would modify the original array, I assume that "without replacement" means that the original array would not be modified. You'd need to make a copy first.

Comment: @Zak: "without replacement" just means the same element won't be sampled multiple times. Not modifying the original slice very well may be another requirement, but isn't specified here.

Comment: Ok, nice one. TIL

Comment: @JimB's definition of "without replacement" is correct. However, this solution is computationally expensive when a is large.

Comment: @alpaca: your example was not large, which makes this an appropriate solution. Otherwise you can either remove random samples from the original set, or if you don't want to modify the set simply record the sample indexes and don't repeat them.

Comment: @alpaca: it's also worth noting that if you're sampling a significant portion of `a`, this is optimal since you'll be calculating random values for, and copying the majority of values anyway. Shuffling the array (via i.e. an optimum Fisher-Yates) vs n random samples are both `O(n)` operations, so overall computation time converges as n approaches len(a).

Comment: record the sample indexes and don't repeat them >> would you be able to demonstrate how to do this if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how random the sample needs to be, I'd probably copy the elements into a `map[T]struct{}` (where `T` is the result type) and `range` over that for my result.

```
// assume input is []int
res := make([]int, len(input))
desorted := make(map[int]struct{})

for _, v := range input {
        desorted[v] = struct{}
}

i := 0
for k, _ := range desorted {
        res[i] = k
        i++
}
```